# Error 0x80070005 from SHGetKnownFolderPath after starting process though service

Tags: c++, winapi, service, process

Im using the code below to get the appdata folder. Normally it works, but if I start the same process though a service using a similar way to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36581/Interaction-between-services-and-applications-at-u) I get the error `0x80070005` which means `Access Denied`.

```
HRESULT result;
if ((result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    FOLDERID_RoamingAppData,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &appdate)) != S_OK)
{
    std::cout << result << std::endl

    return false;
}
```

The function that creates the process is

```
if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        executablePath,
        executableName,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,
        0,
        &startupInfo,
        &processInformation))
    {
        SHOW_SERVICE_ERROR;
    }
```

I have not found anything related to this in the internet. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your program launched under user account with app data folder?

Comment: @VTT - this not play role. play role - `token` - from where ?

Comment: No, the service is running under localsystem account, but the newly created process should be run under user account

Comment: Token from `WTSQueryUserToken(sessions[i].SessionId, &tokenBuffer)` @RbMm

Comment: `localsystem` does not have all the expected profile folders, it's not a user and is local to the system so the `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` does not exist (it can't roam).

Comment: @RichardCritten - but token, how op say not from localsyste, but from some user profile. so localsystem here not related

Comment: The process is running under my user but loading other folderid's does work

Comment: MS-Windows does not switch user like Linux, when you impersonate (use another token) you are still running with the profile of the original user but with the access rights of the new token.  The impersonated user's profile, registry hive, etc are not loaded.

Comment: @RichardCritten - not need any user switch. al info in token. if token taked from running session - it profile must be loaded in registry

Comment: @RbMm OP says it only fails when: running as a service (in the question) and under the localsystem account (comment 3). So there must be impersonation to get a user token.  Note that _"CreateProcessAsUser does not load the specified user's profile into the HKEY_USERS registry key."_ from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten - yes `CreateProcessAsUser` not loaded profile to which token referenced. but if it get from already running user session - `WTSQueryUserToken` - profile already loaded

Comment: @RichardCritten - as note `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` exist for `LocalSystem` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your error that you not pass `lpEnvironment` parameter to `CreateProcess` call.

> **lpEnvironment** [in, optional]
>
> A pointer to the environment block for the new process. If this
>   parameter is **NULL**, the new process uses the environment of the
>   calling process.

as result child process uses the environment of the calling process. what effect this give to `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` ? during resolve `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` - we usually got `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` - and final result will be depend from value of `%USERPROFILE%`. in your case - it will be inherited from service (`LocalSystem`) and will be look like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` - so final path must look like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming`. before return this path to caller - system check are path exist - call `GetFileAttributes`. and here it fail (due security permission) - last error - 5 - `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. and api final return `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)` which is `80070005`.

conclusion - in call `CreateProcessAsUser` use pointer to environment block returned by [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270(v=vs.85).aspx). and free this block later by [`DestroyEnvironmentBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762274(v=vs.85).aspx). also not forget `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` flag in call `CreateProcessAsUser`

also your error can easy be reproduced in local (not elevated) process by next code:

```
SetEnvironmentVariableW(L"USERPROFILE", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile");
PWSTR appdate;
HRESULT result;
if ((result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    FOLDERID_RoamingAppData,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &appdate)) == S_OK)
{
    CoTaskMemFree(appdate);
}
```

if we will be set invalid path in `USERPROFILE` - we got `80070003` error - `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)`

Comment: I also tested running directly from Service itself (not sub-process), which results to `0x80070002` == `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)` as well (hence this API is useless in Elevated/Admin Apps?).

Comment: @Top-Master - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) is 80070003 however. so possibly you typo

Comment: What is 0x80070002 then?

Comment: @Top-Master - The system cannot find the file specified.